# HTML / CSS : automatically center input text following device width

Tags: css, html

I am trying to center 2 input text into my mobile web page.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="servers">
    <input type="text" name="text-basic" id="text-basic" value="dfrferf" class="btn_private_server">
    <input type="text" name="text-basic" id="text-basic" value="gtgtrgrt" class="btn_public_server">
</div>
```

I don't know how to do it.

**CSS**

```
.servers {
    display: table-caption;
    margin: 40px;
}

#text-basic {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate ids which is invalid

Comment: Any reason to use `display: table-caption;` ?

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/BbNeK/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 .servers {

  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: And just another question, how can i improve the size of my input text without lost the position (centered) of my divs?

Comment: I am not clear.Do you want to increase the size of input element?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you input fields can not have the same id. use clases instead.

**EDIT:**
Actually you have just used your classes as ids and ids as classes, put the text-basic into the input classes and the value of the classes into the ids.

A simple way to center them could be:

```
input {
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer, also change your text box id they can not be the same

```
.servers {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to center the text, i would like to center divs

Comment: you want div with class server to be in center, then apply text-align:center to its parent

Answer (score 0):

Please give same class name for both textbox and give text-align:centre style for the class.